# IF ELSE error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement

This is my code; it should print 'BUY' but prints 'NONE'. Doesn't give any ideas.

What to do?

```
DECLARE @avg8 as decimal(18,4)
DECLARE @avg3 as decimal(18,4)
SET @avg8=32.4
SET @avg3=31.5

    IF @avg3 >= @avg8
        BEGIN
        PRINT N'BUY';
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @avg3<@avg8
            BEGIN       
            PRINT N'SELL';
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            PRINT N'none';
            END
    END
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why would it print buy - you have this:
    SET @avg8=32.4
    SET @avg3=31.5

```
IF @avg3 >= @avg8
    BEGIN
    PRINT N'BUY';
```

where @avg3 clearly isn't greater than @avg8

Comment: sorry for that,a silly mistake made by me

Comment: we've all made mistakes like that!

Answer (score 0):

How it will? `@avg3` is less than `@avg8`

```
DECLARE @avg8 as decimal(18,4)
DECLARE @avg3 as decimal(18,4)
SET @avg8=32.4
SET @avg3=31.5

IF @avg3 <= @avg8
    BEGIN
    PRINT N'BUY';
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @avg3>@avg8
        BEGIN       
        PRINT N'SELL';
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        PRINT N'none';
        END
END
```

Comment: sorry for that,a silly mistake made by me